# Highlight dropdown value for a mandatory field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field called Block material which needs to be a mandatory field, so i wrote a condition to notify user to select the value from dropdown. I would like to highlight this field when it gives an alert. How do i do this? The below code doesnt work for dropdown but works for a text field.

```
var blockMaterial = document.getElementById("BLOCK_MATERIAL");
if (blockMaterial.value == "") {    
  $("#STATUSDIVID").removeAttr('class').addClass('div-error').html("Please select an option from the Block Material dropdown");
    $("#testingDynoForm #BLOCK_MATERIAL").css("background-color","#F6CED8");
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
```

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(blockMaterial.options[blockMaterial.selectedIndex].value == "") {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: How do I select dropdown value and put a condition, suppose the field has   '-SELECT-' as first value , how to assign a value to it in IF condition? if(blockMaterial.val =='-SELECT-' )doesn't work, when i alert it says object HTMLInputElement, what condition is applicable here?

Comment: Give first option like this <option>--Select--</option>. So if there is no option selected, it will give blank when get that value.

Comment: can u help me from the scratch, how do i retrieve the dropdown value in a variable and check for the first drop down value cos var blockMaterial = document.getElementById("BLOCK_MATERIAL"); if(blockMaterial.options[blockMaterial.selectedIndex].value) == "0") doesnt work..